# Harmonic series sum function in R

Tags: r, while-loop, sum

I am trying to write a function which takes a positive real number and keeps adding terms of the harmonic series until the total sum exceeds the initial argument. 
I need my function to display the total number of terms of the series that were added.

Here's my code so far:

```
harmonic<-function(n){
  x<-c(0,1)
  while (length(x) < n) {
    position <- length(x)
    new <- 1/(x[position] + x[position-1])
    x <- c(x,new)
  }
  return(x)
}
```

I apologise for the errors in my code, unfortunately I have been working with R only for a month and this is the first time that I am using the while loop and I couldn't find any useful information around.

Thank you, I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello. It is not super clear what the question is. Can you clarify a bit? Maybe provide an example with the expected output?

Comment: (1) Does `n` really represent the sum or rather the number of terms? (2) Do you want to use the harmonic series, i.e. *1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ...*? Your code looks quite different.

Comment: For example if I put harmonic(5) the expected output should be 1  1/2  1/3  1/4 ecc.. (the numbers don't have to be necessarily fractions) which are the numbers from the harmonic series until their sum reaches 5. I wanted to put an image of the harmonic series to make it more clear but since it's my first question I wasn't able to. @flodel

Comment: @SvenHohenstein n should represent the sum. I know my code is completely wrong. It's the best I could do so far since I couldn't find a similar use of the while loop on the internet.

Comment: @Bardee - is there an upper limit for `n` for this problem? I can think of a naive solution, but it doesn't scale well for large values. E.g. - `cumsum(1/1:10)` will give you the sums for the first 10 values in the series.

Comment: @thelatemail n wouldn't be higher than 20 in my case so that should work.

Comment: `f <- function(n) min(which(cumsum(1 / 1:1e5) > n)); f(10)` hmm 20 is going to be pretty large

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt based on some info from this post at maths.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/496116
I can't speak as to whether it is highly accurate in all circumstances or even the best or an appropriate way to go about this. Caveat emptor.

```
harmsum.cnt <- function(x,tol=1e-09) {
  em.cons <- 0.577215664901533
  difffun  <- function(x,n) x - (log(n) + em.cons + 1/(2*n) - 1/(12*n^2))
  ceiling(uniroot(difffun, c(1, 1e10), tol = tol, x = x)$root)
}
```

Seems to work alright though:

```
harmsum.cnt(7)
#[1] 616

harmsum.cnt(15)
#[1] 1835421
```

Compare:

```
tail(cumsum(1/1:616),1); tail(cumsum(1/1:615),1)
#7.001274
#6.999651

dput(tail(cumsum(1/1:1835421),1)); dput(tail(cumsum(1/1:1835420),1))
#15.0000003782678
#14.9999998334336
```

Comment: I was going to suggest a 'cheat', too :-) . I suppose the OP is just flailing due to an inability to write out what the harmonic series is, tho'

Answer (score 1):

This is a partial answer, which I'll try to fill in later.  On the assumption that you want an exact answer, rather than the excellent approximation formula thelatemail found,  there are a few tools to consider.

First,  use of a hash-table or memoise methods will allow you to save previous calculations, thus saving a lot of time.

Second, since the sum of a (finite) sequence is independent of the grouping, you can calculate, e.g.  the first N terms and the second (N+1):2N  terms independently.  Use `parallel` package to divide and conquer.

Third,  before you get too deep into the morass, check the limits of floating-point accuracy via a call to `.Machine$double.eps` Once your `1/n` term comes close to that, you'll need to switch over to `gmp` and `Rmpfr` to get full accuracy in your calculations.

Now, just to clarify what you "should" be doing,  a correct loop is

```
 mylimit <- [pick a value]
        harmsum<-0 
        for(k in 1:N){
     harmsum <- harmsum + 1/k
    if (harmsum >= mylimit) break
    }
```

(or similar setup using `while`)